# Calling a method if object is not null (Using null safety with void methods)

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

Is there a way to do such thing as **void?** **callMe()?**
Because there is no type such as **void?** and hence calling this method null object with result in error above.

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {  
     User? user;

     print(user?.callMe());  //This expression has a type of 'void' so its value can't be used.
}
 
class User {
     String name;

     User(this.name);
        
     void? callMe() { 
         print('Hello, $name');
     }      
      
     String? foo(){ // sound null safety String method
         return name;
     }

}
```

Comment: As explained by the error message, you can't use a `void` result.  What do you expect `print`ing it to do?  Just use `user?.callMe()`  without the outer `print` call.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. the ```print()``` function expects an String but I'm feeding a void (or nothing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return a `String` (or `String?` if you want, but it is not necessary in this case) from the `User`'s `callMe` method:

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {  
    User? user;

    print(user?.callMe());
}

class User {
    String name;

    User(this.name);
    
    String callMe() { 
        return 'Hello, $name';
    }      
}
```

It's because `print` method accepts an `Object` as its parameter, and `void` is not an object, but `String` is an `Object`.